# Finding joint density of discrete variables

Tags: self-study, independence, algorithms, joint-distribution

Below is the prompt: Suppose that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent and continuous random variables with densities $f_1$ and $f_2$ respectively. $Z$ is a Bernoulli(p) random variable and independent of $X_1$ and $X_2$. Define $Y = ZX_1 + (1 − Z)X_2$. It asked me to prove that $f_{YZ}(y,z) = [pf_1(y)]^z[(1-p)f_2(y)]^{(1-z)}$.

So I tried the following (based on mixture distributions which people refer to):

We also know that $Y|Z=1 \stackrel{d}{=}X_1 \sim f_1$ and $Y|Z=0 \stackrel{d}{=}X_2 \sim f_2$

$Y=ZX_1 + (1-Z)X_2 \implies F_Y(y) =  P(Y\leq y, Z=1) + P(Y\leq y, Z= 0)
= P(Y\leq y|Z=1)P(Z=1) + P(Y\leq y|Z=0)P(Z=0)$

$=P(X_1\leq y)P(Z=1)+ P(X_2\leq y)P(Z=0) $

$ = P(X_1\leq y)p+ P(X_2\leq y)(1-p)$

$f_Y(y) = pf_1(y)+(1-p)f_2(y)$

$f_Z(z) = p^z(1-p)^{1-z}$

So how can I find $f_{YZ}(y,z)$ now given that they are not independent?

Edited version:

We also know that $Y|Z=1 \stackrel{d}{=}X_1 \sim f_1$ and $Y|Z=0 \stackrel{d}{=}X_2 \sim f_2$

$f_{YZ}(y,1) = pf_1(y) $ which is exactly $P(Y,Z=1)
$

$f_{YZ}(y,0) = (1-p)f_2(y)$ which is exactly $P(Y,Z=0)$

Therefore, $f_{YZ}(y,z) = [pf_1(y)]^z[(1-p)f_2(y)]^{(1-z)}$

Comment: Google 'mixture distributions', perhaps reading [Wikipedia's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution) account first.

Comment: Discrete variables do not have joint densities.  $Y$ is a *mixture* variable.  It is continuous.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: Thank you so much everyone! I edited the post and added what I did so far. If you have any hints, please let me know!

Comment: You almost had a complete answer at the point you wrote "We also know that...".  All you have to do is plug in $z=0$ and then $z=1$ in the formula for $f_{YX}$ to verify it gives the correct density.

Comment: I added edited version to the end of the post. Can you please confirm if that's what you meant @whuber?

Comment: Yes, indeed: it looks like you have it.

Comment: thank you so much!!